# TDI for HCL Connections 6.5 synchronization fails with "bad SQL grammar [];" error

Tags: ldap, lotus-domino, ibm-connections, tdi

I'm using Tivoli Directory Integrator (TDI) to sync users from Domino LDAP to the local DB2 people database of HCL Connections. On a test installation, I got the following error when trying to initially sync the users:

```
[root@cnx65 tdisol]# LANG=en_US.utf8 ./sync_all_dns.sh 
create synchronization lock
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (server).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
**********
CLFRN1275I: Begin to hash records in database.
CLFRN1269I: Finish hash records in database.
**********
"message": "CLFRN1254E: An error occurred while performing findEntry: {0}."
"exception": "com.ibm.lconn.profiles.api.tdi.service.TDIException: CLFRN1254E: An error occurred while performing findEntry: {0}."
Synchronize of Database Repository failed
```

[HCLs documentation](https://help.hcltechsw.com/connections/v6/admin/troubleshoot/r_error_codes_profiles.html) recommend to check the logs in case of `CLFRN1254E`. The file `logs/SyncUpdates.log` contains the following exception:

```
2020-01-21 07:50:03,803 INFO  [org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.7431103d-4d0a-4d63-bdb7-61e274f23ed4] - CTGDIS092I Use entry provided at runtime as work entry (first pass only).
2020-01-21 07:50:11,723 ERROR [org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.7431103d-4d0a-4d63-bdb7-61e274f23ed4] - [hash_db_entries] CTGDIS181E Error while evaluating the hook 'Function error' in the component 'hash_db_entries (hash_db_entries.functioncall_fail).
com.ibm.lconn.profiles.api.tdi.service.TDIException: CLFRN1254E: An error occurred while executing findEntry: {0}.
        at com.ibm.lconn.profiles.api.tdi.connectors.ProfileConnector$ProfileCodeBlock.handleRecoverable(ProfileConnector.java:1063)
        at com.ibm.lconn.profiles.api.tdi.connectors.Util.TDICodeRunner.run(TDICodeRunner.java:41)
        at com.ibm.lconn.profiles.api.tdi.connectors.ProfileConnector.getNextEntry(ProfileConnector.java:155)
        at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLineComponent.executeOperation(AssemblyLineComponent.java:3370)
        at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLineComponent.getnext(AssemblyLineComponent.java:932)
        at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.msGetNextIteratorEntry(AssemblyLine.java:3689)
        at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeMainStep(AssemblyLine.java:3388)
        at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeMainLoop(AssemblyLine.java:3000)
        at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeMainLoop(AssemblyLine.java:2983)
        at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeAL(AssemblyLine.java:2952)
        at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.run(AssemblyLine.java:1319)
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: SqlMapClient operation; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.
--- Check the TDIProfile.get-InlineParameterMap.
--- Check the statement (query failed).
--- Cause: com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -551, SQLSTATE: 42501, SQLERRMC: LCUSER;SELECT;EMPINST.EMPLOYEE
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:97)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
        at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:212)
        at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.executeWithListResult(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:249)
        at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForList(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:296)
        at com.ibm.lconn.profiles.internal.service.store.sqlmapdao.TDIProfileSqlMapDao.get(TDIProfileSqlMapDao.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
```

**What could be the problem? How could I find out more information why this error occurs?**

### What I already tried

#### Increase log level

In `profiles_tdi.properties` I enabled debug logs for every component:

```
debug_collect=true
debug_draft=true
debug_fill_codes=true
debug_managers=true
debug_photos=true
debug_pronounce=true
debug_special=true
debug_update_profile=true
trace_profile_tdi_javascript=on
```

Since this had no effect, I set the log4j level to debug for the entire application in `etc/log4j.properties`:

```
log3j.rootCategory=DEBUG, Default
```

Also tried `ALL` instead of `DEBUG`. However, there is no change in the output. I expected to see the SQL query, which caused the exception.

#### Set `mode` in properties

[According to this post](https://blog.robertfarstad.com/2014/11/connections-5-external-users-i-walked.html), the `mode` attribute will be used to decide if an user is internal or external. Since the example config says

```
Actually, any string other than "external" is interpreted as employee.
```

it is set to `mode=memberType`. Also tried `mode=uid` and `mode=mail`. Both are fields containing a string not equal to "external", so this should result in all members imported as internal users.

#### Sync single users

Since my LDAP filter applies to around 60 users, I ran `./collect_dns.sh` successfully and removed all users from `collect.dns` file except my own. Then sync the user from the dn file with `./populate_from_dn_file.sh`. This was done for two other users, resulting always in the same error:

```
CLFRN0027I: After operation, success records is 0, duplicate records 0, failure records is 1, and last successful entry is null.
CLFRN1280I: 20200121105123 Iterations total number: 1.
```

The only difference is that `logs/PopulateDBFromDNFile.log` contains more detailled information about the fetched attributes, mappings and so on. Unfortunately, it doesn't really help me in terms of the error, since it produces a similiar message:

```
2020-01-21 10:55:27,530 INFO  [com.ibm.di.log.FileRollerAppender.268b5e1d-d0fc-4a7c-9e12-4d742c44faa5] - [callSyncDB_mod] [add_manager_data] [setup_if_lookup] CTGDIS126I Return false.
2020-01-21 10:55:27,530 INFO  [com.ibm.di.log.FileRollerAppender.268b5e1d-d0fc-4a7c-9e12-4d742c44faa5] - [callSyncDB_mod] [add_manager_data] [setup_if_lookup] CTGDIS123I Returned object class java.lang.Boolean.
2020-01-21 10:55:27,530 INFO  [com.ibm.di.log.FileRollerAppender.268b5e1d-d0fc-4a7c-9e12-4d742c44faa5] - [callSyncDB_mod] [add_manager_data] CTGDIS075I Trying to exit TaskCallBlock.
2020-01-21 10:55:27,531 INFO  [com.ibm.di.log.FileRollerAppender.268b5e1d-d0fc-4a7c-9e12-4d742c44faa5] - [callSyncDB_mod] [add_manager_data] CTGDIS076I Succeeded exiting TaskCallBlock.
2020-01-21 10:55:27,531 INFO  [com.ibm.di.log.FileRollerAppender.268b5e1d-d0fc-4a7c-9e12-4d742c44faa5] - [callSyncDB_mod] [add_manager_data] CTGDIS057I Hook after_functioncall not enabled.
2020-01-21 10:55:27,531 INFO  [com.ibm.di.log.FileRollerAppender.268b5e1d-d0fc-4a7c-9e12-4d742c44faa5] - [callSyncDB_mod] CTGDIS352I Use null Behavior for $_already_lookup_manager.
2020-01-21 10:55:27,531 INFO  [com.ibm.di.log.FileRollerAppender.268b5e1d-d0fc-4a7c-9e12-4d742c44faa5] - [callSyncDB_mod] CTGDIS351I Map Attribute $manager_uid [1].
2020-01-21 10:55:27,531 INFO  [com.ibm.di.log.FileRollerAppender.268b5e1d-d0fc-4a7c-9e12-4d742c44faa5] - [callSyncDB_mod] CTGDIS353I Script is: conn["$manager_uid"]
2020-01-21 10:55:27,531 INFO  [com.ibm.di.log.FileRollerAppender.268b5e1d-d0fc-4a7c-9e12-4d742c44faa5] - [callSyncDB_mod] CTGDIS352I Use null Behavior for $manager_uid.
2020-01-21 10:55:27,531 INFO  [com.ibm.di.log.FileRollerAppender.268b5e1d-d0fc-4a7c-9e12-4d742c44faa5] - [callSyncDB_mod] [add_manager_data] CTGDIS057I Hook functioncall_ok not enabled.
2020-01-21 10:55:27,531 INFO  [com.ibm.di.log.FileRollerAppender.268b5e1d-d0fc-4a7c-9e12-4d742c44faa5] - [callSyncDB_mod] [add_manager_data] CTGDIS057I Hook default_ok not enabled.
2020-01-21 10:55:27,538 INFO  [com.ibm.di.log.FileRollerAppender.268b5e1d-d0fc-4a7c-9e12-4d742c44faa5] - [callSyncDB_mod] Result: <My Name of the User in dn file>
2020-01-21 10:55:27,591 ERROR [com.ibm.di.log.FileRollerAppender.268b5e1d-d0fc-4a7c-9e12-4d742c44faa5] - [callSyncDB_mod] [ProfileConnector] SqlMapClient operation; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.
--- Check the TDIProfile.get-InlineParameterMap.
--- Check the statement (query failed).
--- Cause: com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -551, SQLSTATE: 42501, SQLERRMC: LCUSER;SELECT;EMPINST.EMPLOYEE
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that this was a unlucky logical mistake from me. The database is created using sql files, shipped with the Connections Installation Wizard. I automatically import them in a loop. Since it was very slow (about 30 min for all scripts), I tried to parallelize them by adding a `&` at the end of the command and finally `wait` at the end to make sure all scripts were executed.

```
- name: Check and create non existing DBs for CNX
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ db2.instance.name }}"
  shell: |
    db={{ item.name }}
    scripts=({{ item.files | join(' ') }})
    existing_dbs=$(echo -e '{{ existing_dbs.stdout }}')
    echo "Check db ${db}"

    if ! echo ${existing_dbs} | grep -q ${db}; then
      echo "DB ${db} doesn't exist, execute scripts"
      for script in "${scripts[@]}"
      do
        echo "${db}: Execute script ${script}"
        {{ db2.target }}/bin/db2 -td@ -f {{ cnx_sql_dir }}/${script} &
      done
      wait
    fi
  register: db_check
  changed_when: "'execute scripts' in db_check.stdout"
  loop: "{{ cnx.db_scripts }}"
```

`cnx.db_scripts` is a mapping of database names to SQL files:

```
  db_scripts:
    - name: PEOPLEDB
      files:
        - profiles/db2/createDb.sql
        - profiles/db2/appGrants.sql
    - name: FORUM
      files: 
         # - ...
```

In retrospect, this was a terrible logical mistake because I missed the fact that those scripts rely on each other: When `profiles/db2/appGrants.sql` is executed before `profiles/db2/createDb.sql` was finished, it wouldn't work because the db doesn't exists.

As a result, TDIs queries failed because the database and tables were only partly created. I didn't notice this immediately, since the machine was several re-deployed during of the Ansible playbook development. Strangely, TDI only failed in 2 of 10 deployments. Seems like DB2 make some kind of queue and depending on the timing, the people database required for TDI is created successfully on some runs.